# how to display bootstrap datetime picker using laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, bootstrap-5, datetimepicker

`your text`i'm trying to display the bootstrap datetime picker in my blade file but a text field displays instead
here is my blade file code :
`

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@include('navbar.header')
@section('content')
@include('sidebar.form')

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                useCurrent: false,
                sideBySide: true,
                minDate: moment(),
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('node_modules/bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('node_modules/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js') }}"></script>

@endsection
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">Date d'expiration</label>
                {{--<div class="col-8" >
                    @error('expire')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror 
                </div> --}}
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="expire" id="datetimepicker" required/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>`
```

`your text`
at first i tried the html input field datetime-local but it doesn't match my requirements because i want the user to choose a datetime from the current date and onwards and it's giving me to select between a range of time witch i don't want i want the user to be able to choose the date he wants in the future for his records
that's why i tried the bootstrap datetime picker but it does not diplay.
any help!